# How to remove the suffix .html in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

How I can remove the suffix .html in joomla 3 in my menu link even if I turn on Add URLs suffix.

I want to remove in one specific article/page only. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This solution is not recommended because it hacks core Joomla library.

Assume that the alias of your menu item is `about`. Open the file

```
/libraries/cms/router/site.php
```

and around the line #116, find this line:

```
if ($app->get('sef_suffix') && !(substr($route, -9) == 'index.php' || substr($route, -1) == '/'))
```

then replace it with this one:

```
if ($app->get('sef_suffix') && !(substr($route, -9) == 'index.php' || substr($route, -1) == '/') && $route != 'index.php/about')
```

It is obvious that you must replace `about` with your menu item alias in the above line.

Comment: Hi Farahmand, Great, thanks a lot, it works perfectly. As you said it is not recommended but I think this is the answer for my problem.

Comment: You're welcome Dennis - Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to remove the extension for a single menu item, but you might be able to do it using your `.htacces` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^/about.html$ /about [L]
```

Comment: Hi johanpw, Thank you for the time answering my question but when I try it is not working by the way nice idea.